# How to set maximum numeric value for SQL variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, math

How to limit the value of **X** at **100.0000** and not let it go to **105.8968**?

```
SELECT ((15898 / (15898 + 401 + 36) * 100) + (8572 * 0.001)) AS `X`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LEAST](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-greatest-least/) function:

```
SELECT (LEAST(100, 
              (15898 / (15898 + 401 + 36) * 100) + (8572 * 0.001)
             )
       ) AS `X`
```

**Additional:** To find maximum (reverse of Least), you can use [GREATEST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function

From [documentation of Least()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

> **LEAST(value1,value2,...)**
>
> With two or more arguments, returns the smallest (minimum-valued)
>   argument. The arguments are compared using the following rules:
>
> If any argument is NULL, the result is NULL. No comparison is needed.
>
> If all arguments are integer-valued, they are compared as integers.
>
> If at least one argument is double precision, they are compared as double-precision values. Otherwise, if at least one argument is a
>   DECIMAL value, they are compared as DECIMAL values.
>
> If the arguments comprise a mix of numbers and strings, they are compared as numbers.
>
> If any argument is a nonbinary (character) string, the arguments are compared as nonbinary strings.
>
> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as binary strings.
>
> The return type of LEAST() is the aggregated type of the comparison
>   argument types.

Comment: This will invoke (potentially expensive) type juggling, I think. @GordonLinoff answer should not, I think.

Comment: @bishop from documentation: "If at least one argument is double precision, they are compared as double-precision values. Otherwise, if at least one argument is a DECIMAL value, they are compared as DECIMAL values." So I dont think so, it will have type juggling issues. Ready to be corrected if I am wrong!

Comment: Yes, "compared as double precision" means all those that are _not_ double precision will be type juggled _into_ double precision. This has a cost. Perhaps inconsequential, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEAST()`:

```
SELECT LEAST((15898 / (15898 + 401 + 36) * 100) + (8572 * 0.001), 100.0000) AS `X`
```